# How can I get apache virtual host to work?

Tags: apache-2.2, subdomain, xampp

OK I have been battling this for a week,

I have Xampp running on my home server and I am trying to get subdomains to work, I edited my windows host file so that all of these load my site,

http://localhost/
http://mydomain.com/

http://images.mydomain.com/
http://images.localhost/

I then modified my Apache conf file to add my virtual host to make the images.mydomain.com and images.localhost to load up my localhost/images folder but for some reason they load the contents of http://localhost/ as if I am going to the regular site and not a subdomain, any idea why?

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /htdocs/images/
    ServerName images.localhost
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /htdocs/images/
    ServerName images.mydomain.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /htdocs/
    ServerName mydomain.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: You didn't include the 'http://' in your hosts file, did you?

Comment: no serrverfault filters changed those into links on me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to delete the trailing slash on the ServerName lines.

Comment: yeah I did that but no luck either

Answer (score 0):

Or give the full path to the folder:

DocumentRoot c:/htdocs/mydomain
    ServerName mydomain.com/

Comment: yes I added full path and restart apache but no luck

Answer (score 0):

What happened if you ping to images.mydomain.com?
Do you obtain a response from your server?

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to add " to DocumentRoot. You should try something like this 
DocumentRoot "/htdocs/images/"

Answer (score 0):

Did you fill your /etc/hosts with the entry images.localhost ?